# How to make entire mvc application root relative?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way I can set in one place my entire mvc5 application to be root relative throughout?

It would be so much cleaner if everywhere in my code `/` just meant `~/`.

If this is a duplicate, great. I just couldn't find it.

*Side Note: It was working this way, I had a Web.sitemap that has always had just `/` and it was working even with my root not being the absolute web root but it suddenly stopped working and going to the absolute web root instead of my app root and I'm  not sure why. So I think this is possible and I had it configured to do what I wanted to, but just didn't know the setting and therefore lost it somehow accidentally.*

Comment: Can you be a little specific? What is the reason of this requirement?

Comment: @student, the reason would be 1. simplicity (within my app, `/` refers to my app root) and 2. as in my side note, I think I had it this way without realizing it at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not answer your question, still I would suggest you to **not try to use** `/` as `~/`.

> Why?

- This may cause you issues in future
- The settings may be working on your machine
- Deployments to other machines will break the code
- Regular updates may also cause your code to break

Even if you're planning to change this mapping, I would highly recommend that you don't do it

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. I'm just left with the mystery of why my application was working with / before whereas now it's not. Thanks. If I don't get someone to tell me the setting, your answer will be the one. There may not even be a setting...

Comment: @toddmo We'll not get anything for this. Yes, we can write a function which will take `/` when you pass `~/` to it, but that will be playing against the patterns